# Powershell HTTPIE

Tags: api, powershell, httpie

I'm trying to POST the following but I keep getting an error:

*"http: error: argument REQUEST_ITEM: "with" is not a valid value"*

`http POST https://someurl.com fields:='{\"example-api-identifier\":\"String with spaces\"}' Token:randomnumbers`

How do I escape these spaces? I'm assuming that's the issue here?

Comment: Maybe `fields:='{"example-api-identifier":"String with spaces"}'` ?

Comment: that doesn't seem to work :/

Answer (score 0):

I don't personally know about powershell, but httpie should be fine with spaces without needing the := syntax

```
$ http POST http://httpbin.org/post example-api-identifier="String with spaces"
```

yields

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: close
Content-Length: 413
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sat, 01 Feb 2020 00:25:41 GMT
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0

{
    "args": {},
    "data": "{\"example-api-identifier\": \"String with spaces\"}",
    "files": {},
    "form": {},
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json, */*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Content-Length": "48",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Host": "httpbin.org",
        "User-Agent": "HTTPie/1.0.0"
    },
    "json": {
        "example-api-identifier": "String with spaces"
    },
    "origin": "127.0.0.1",
    "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```